# authorized_key: Join all keys of subelements in order to make the list of keys exclusive

Tags: python, python-3.x, ansible

I want to deploy ssh keys of a list of users. The provided list of keys need to be exclusive, so if a key is being removed from the user, this should be reflected in the authorized_keys-file.

### My current state

I am using this ansible playbook to deploy SSH keys for given users with a subset of publicKeys.

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  vars_files:
    - /ansible/vault.yml
  vars:
    ansible_become_password: "{{ become_password }}"
    becomeSecret: "{{ become_password }}"
  roles:
    - users
```

The role's `tasks/main.yml`:

```
---
- name: Create users and set passwords
  user:
    name: "{{ item.username }}"
    password: "{{ item.password | password_hash('sha512', 65534 | random(seed=inventory_hostname) | string)}}"
    createhome: yes
    shell: /bin/bash
  with_items: "{{ users }}"

- name: Add SSH Keys for each users
  ansible.posix.authorized_key:
    user: "{{ item.username }}"
    key: "{{ item.publicKeys | join('\n') }}"
    exclusive: true
  loop: "{{ users }}"
```

The user's var looks like this:

```yaml
# local_vars.yml

ansible_user: "vagrant"
ansible_ssh_private_key_file: "~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key"
ansible_ssh_common_args: "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
ansible_become_password: "my_become_password"
become_password: "fooBar"
publicKey: "ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAINmGBkR7E5WNtyegqWEYcOJtbRwi64QkSewAS5oox2mT test@local"

users:
  - username: "TestUser1"
    password: "TestPassword1"
    publicKeys:
      - "ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAINmGBkR7E5WNtyegqWEYcOJtbRwi64QkSewAS5oox2mT test1@local"
      - "ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAINmGBkR7E5WNtyegqWEYcOJtbRwi64QkSewAS5oox2mT test2@local"
  - username: "TestUser2"
    password: "TestPassword2"
    publicKeys:
      - "ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAINmGBkR7E5WNtyegqWEYcOJtbRwi64QkSewAS5oox2mT test3@local"
      - "ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAINmGBkR7E5WNtyegqWEYcOJtbRwi64QkSewAS5oox2mT test4@local"
  - username: "TestUser3"
    password: "TestPassword3"
    publicKeys:
      - "ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAINmGBkR7E5WNtyegqWEYcOJtbRwi64QkSewAS5oox2mT test5@local"
      - "ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAINmGBkR7E5WNtyegqWEYcOJtbRwi64QkSewAS5oox2mT test6@local"
```

### The goal

I want to have those keys exclusively. So if I deployed a key and remove it from the publicKeys-list of a user later on, I want the deleted key no longer to be present.

### The problem

Running the playbook results in this output:

```
TASK [users : Add SSH Keys for each users] ***************************************************
changed: [192.168.56.4] => (item={'username': 'TestUser1', 'password': 'TestPassword1', 'publicKeys': ['ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAINmGBkR7E5WNtyegqWEYcOJtbRwi64QkSewAS5oox2mT test1@local', 'ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAINmGBkR7E5WNtyegqWEYcOJtbRwi64QkSewAS5oox2mT test2@local']})
changed: [192.168.56.4] => (item={'username': 'TestUser2', 'password': 'TestPassword2', 'publicKeys': ['ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAINmGBkR7E5WNtyegqWEYcOJtbRwi64QkSewAS5oox2mT test3@local', 'ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAINmGBkR7E5WNtyegqWEYcOJtbRwi64QkSewAS5oox2mT test4@local']})
changed: [192.168.56.4] => (item={'username': 'TestUser3', 'password': 'TestPassword3', 'publicKeys': ['ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAINmGBkR7E5WNtyegqWEYcOJtbRwi64QkSewAS5oox2mT test5@local', 'ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAINmGBkR7E5WNtyegqWEYcOJtbRwi64QkSewAS5oox2mT test6@local']})
```

But still the authorized-keys file on the server includes exclusively the last key provided in the variable:

```
root@server1:/home/TestUser1/.ssh# cat /home/TestUser1/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAINmGBkR7E5WNtyegqWEYcOJtbRwi64QkSewAS5oox2mT test2@local
root@server1:/home/TestUser1/.ssh# cat /home/TestUser2/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAINmGBkR7E5WNtyegqWEYcOJtbRwi64QkSewAS5oox2mT test4@local
root@server1:/home/TestUser1/.ssh# cat /home/TestUser3/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAINmGBkR7E5WNtyegqWEYcOJtbRwi64QkSewAS5oox2mT test6@local
```

### Additional information

This is my ansible version:

```
ansible [core 2.16.2]
  config file = /Users/ahoi/Entwicklung/ansible/exampleansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/Users/ahoi/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/9.1.0/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /Users/ahoi/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /opt/homebrew/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.12.1 (main, Dec  7 2023, 20:45:44) [Clang 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)] (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ansible/9.1.0/libexec/bin/python)
  jinja version = 3.1.2
  libyaml = True
```

Comment: Well, your public keys seem to be the exact same with only the comment part (`test1@local` and `test2@local` etc.) being different. Have you tried that with **actually different** keys? Note that the comment part won't matter on the actual use of the key anyways so you don't need to have multiple of them.

Comment: Yeah, that's the solution.

But: Shouldn't there be a information that a key has been skipped?

Comment: The key hasn't really been skipped since its the exact same key. The reason that duplication is skipped though is because the Python code for that task is using a dictionary with the keys being the actual key part (the base 64 string part) of your public key. If you want that repetition raise an issue on their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ansible-collections/ansible.posix)

Comment: ^-- In practice, this would be of no value, though, because what is matched during the SSH handshake between the client and the server is the public key, not its description, you could even have no public key at all in the client and have any description you want on the server, the handshake would still be valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the documentation you linked above:

> Multiple keys can be specified in a single `key` string value by separating them by newlines.

All you have to do is loop over your users, get the list of keys and join them with a new line.

Note: `exclusive` is not loop safe if you add keys for the same user. It is of course safe if you loop over different users and add the keys at once.

The following task should meet your requirement

```yaml
    - name: Add SSH Keys for each users
      ansible.posix.authorized_key:
        user: "{{ item.username }}"
        key: "{{ item.publicKeys | join('\n') }}"
        exclusive: true
      loop: "{{ users }}"
```

Note: I kept your variable names. But if you ever want to pass your playbook through `ansible-lint` you should stick to the coding standards: `publicKeys` should be renamed `public_keys`.

Comment: Thank you. But this leads to the problem that only the last key for every user is being inserted.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, this inserts all keys for a specific user at once.

Comment: I tested it on my local vagrant vm and the result is that it does not insert all keys for the user. But to make this more precise, I edited my initial question and referred to this answer including the result I get.

Comment: I don't know how you tested but this is [definitely giving the expected result](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/869eabdf10b69abd5f10c3cf671b985d)

Comment: I tested it on my local setup with a fresh vagrant vm (ubuntu 22.04) as os.

Comment: I also updated my question to reflect the current state better

Comment: @SPQRInc I suspect your result are odd because your two public keys are the same (except for their description). Could you try generating two distinct keys per user?

Comment: @SPQRInc Even with a fresh vagrant box [I still can't reproduce your issue](https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/a08dda0f93f34d0493a874a330a5d0fa) and this is still behaving exactly as expected. As you will see I even went back and fourth between initial and modify state with absolutely no issue.